# Django admin - how to save inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin, inlines

I need to override save method of inlines in admin. While saving photos, I need to add user id to DB column. I cant make it in model because there is no request data there. How can I do it in admin, to somehow get nad set user id?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the save_formset method on ModelAdmin is what you should use:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to django (1.8) and using the above override:

```py
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)  # gets instance from memory and add to it before saving it
    for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
        obj.delete()
    for instance in instances:
        for form in formset:  # cleaned_data is only available on the form, so you have to iterate over formset
            instance.modified_by = request.user
            instance.created_by = request.user
            instance.lowercase_enum_value_en = form.cleaned_data['enum_value_en'].lower()
            instance.save()
    formset.save_m2m()
```

i.e. adding to it before saving the instance and form, however when the user enters 2 lines it always saves the last cleaned_data['enum_value_en'].