# Customize Django poll admin functionality

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I would like to customize the admin poll functionality in Django. Is it possible to override or add to existing functionality of admin site?

For example in the screenshot shown, I would like to add different functionality than what it automatically does when I click on "SAVE". I am new to Django and html, a brief procedure is greatly appreciated.
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin's `save` method exist to save the model instance to the database.

If you like to add extra functionality to the [admin's save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), simply override the method inside the `ModelAdmin` class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = [...]
    list_filter = [...]
    # etc.

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # do stuff here 

        # and don't forget to call super's save method
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that quick response. Is it possible to access content I entered in the ballot creation page from this function? For example I want to access "Ballot Text" or "Ballot Address". Is it possible to access it from this save method?

Comment: Of course you can. Just access `obj.ballot_text` or `obj.ballot_address`.

Comment: thanks again. How I can access variable number of choices?

Comment: What do you mean by that (*variable number of choices*)?

Comment: From screenshot if you see there are choices. How I can access them from Save method? I got Ballot Text, Address but how about Choice text's and choice addresses?

Comment: Because `choices` is an inline form inside the `ballot`, to access `choices` you should override [`save_formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset).

Comment: Thanks again. 
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
       for f in formset:
          print('Voter address is: ', f['voter_address'] )
      super().save_formset(request,form, formset, change)

I get output as 
Voter address is:  <input class="vTextField" id="id_choice_set-0-voter_address" maxlength="36" name="choice_set-0-voter_address" type="text" value="klncklas," />

But how I can get value? "klncklas," is what I am looking for

Comment: I am afraid that should be asked as a separate question, in order to be searchable by the community. However, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988878/django-admin-how-to-save-inlines).

Comment: I have added a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054736/django-extract-value-from-formset) can you please have a look and let me know the answer