# Django, extract value from formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, formset

I have overridden save_formset method to extract data from admin page. Here is how my code looks like:

```py
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    for f in formset:
        print('Voter address is: ', f['voter_address'])
    super().save_formset(request,form, formset, change)
```

I get output as:

[image]

But I want to extract actual value which is "klncklas," and for second one I would like to know that there is no value present. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    # Create instances. Each instance will be a "row" (obj) of the inline model
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    # Iterate over the instances (objects of the Inline Model)
    for instance in instances:
        # Get the object's attribute (Model field)
        print(instance.voter_address)
    super().save_formset(request,form, formset, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [save_formset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset), you need to use [formset.save(commit=False)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to get the submitted inline objects in Django Admin as shown below. *Don't worry `formset.save(commit=False)` does not save objects but does return objects while `formset.save()` equivalent to `formset.save(commit=True)` does save and return objects:

```py
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    for f in formset.save(commit=False): # Here
        print('Voter address is: ', f['voter_address'])
    super().save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848605/django-modelform-what-is-savecommit-false-used-for/76222277#76222277) explaining about `save(commit=False)` vs `save()` and how to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin.